# Jenkins stop working as soon as I change java version from 1.8 to 1.7 with update-alternatives --config java command

Tags: java, jenkins

I have the below setup...

HOST: RHEL 7.3
JAVA: java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel and 
      java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel installed on the host

Jenkins is making use of java.version 1.8.0_131 and running perfectly fine, but as soon as I change the version of java to 1.7 with update-alternatives --config java command and restart jenkins it stops working.

Firing netstat -a -n | grep 8080 command displays nothing which seems to me that as soon as I changed the java version from 1.8 to 1.7 java/jenkins has stopped listening.
Please help me out in understanding how can I change java version and still manage jenkins to work.

Note: I wanted to change java version in my host only.

```
[rahul@ip-172-31-1-14 ~]$ sudo update-alternatives --config java

There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
   1           java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.141-2.6.10.1.el7_3.x86_64/jre/bin/java)
*+ 2           java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64/jre/bin/java)

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 

[rahul@ip-172-31-1-14 ~]$ sudo lsof -i :8080
COMMAND  PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    4589 jenkins  158u  IPv6  52390      0t0  TCP *:webcache (LISTEN)

[rahul@ip-172-31-1-14 ~]$ netstat -a -n | grep 8080
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

The above are the results with java 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

This could relate to your jenkins version. Since [2.54 (04-09-2017)](https://jenkins.io/changelog/) you have to use Java 8 to run jenkins.

If you are using CentOS the yum-repo contains version 2.46 and 2.60. You can use [`sudo yum downgrade`](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/29617) to downgrade to jenkins 2.46.

Comment: No talaub, I was using Jenkins with java 1.7 a month ago with the latest jenkins version and it was running without any issues. For some reason I need to tear down my configuration and reconfigure everything. Since then I am not able to use Jenkins with java 1.7